# How to write a function for datewise value changeing?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is a table what I use to configure date options.

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
|   id  |   date  |   amount  |
+-------+---------+-----------+
|    1  | 5       | 200       |
|    2  | 15      | 500       |
|    3  | 25      | 1000      |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

In my case I check the current date and want to compare it to my database date and return corresponding amount. For example

If current date is 6-15 i have to add 200 with the base amount.

If current date is 16-25 i have to add 500 with the base amount.

If current date is 26- next 5 i have to add 1000 with the base amount.

I am using Codeigniter. How should I do it?

```
public function add_fee($dt) {

        $not_paid = 'Not Yet Paid';
        $late_fee = $this->get_amount($dt);
        $this->db->where('date', $not_paid);
        $this->db->set('due', 'due'+$late_fee, FALSE);
        $this->db->update('fee');        
    }
```

I am facing problem with writing `get_amount($dt);

give me some idea. Do i have to change my late_fee table? or something else?

Comment: do you want to use from above table for updating another table?

Comment: yes! use from the table i described first. and updatinfg another table which code I Written bellow

Comment: @freaky_coder *If current date is 16-25 i have to add 500* why 500 why not 1000, 16-25 range matches with 1000 not with 500 same with third case

Comment: till 25 its 500. from 26 its 1000

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$from, $to`parameters instead of `$dt` to `get_amount()` or can make `$from, $to` var inside `get_amount()` by same condition. You can try like this...

```
function get_amount( $from, $to )
{
    $this->db->select('amount');
    $this->db->where('date>=', $from);
    $this->db->where('date<=', $to);
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->amount;
    }
    return 0;
}

function add_fee($dt) {
    $not_paid = 'Not Yet Paid';
    $from = ''; $to = '';
    if($dt >=6 && $dt <= 15){
        $from = 6; $to = 15;
    }elseif($dt >=16 && $dt <= 25){
        $from = 16; $to = 25;
    }elseif($dt >=26 && $dt <= 30){
        $from = 26; $to = 30;
    }
    $late_fee = $this->get_amount($from, $to);
    $this->db->where('date', $not_paid);
    $this->db->set('due', 'due'+$late_fee, FALSE);
    $this->db->update('fee');
}
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '16 AND `date<=` 25' at line 3

SELECT `amount` FROM (`late_fee`) WHERE `date>=` 16 AND `date<=` 25

This happening now! Does not codeigniter active record suport <= >= operations?

Comment: Yes! support. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about...

```
 DROP TABLE my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,date  INT NOT NULL
 ,amount  INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1  ,5       ,200       ),
 (2  ,15      ,500       ),
 (3  ,25      ,1000      );

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-04' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-04' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                0 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                0 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                1 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-08' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-08' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                1 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                0 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                0 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-12' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-12' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                1 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                0 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                0 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-16' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-16' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                0 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                1 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                0 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-20' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-20' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                0 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                1 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                0 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-24' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-24' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                0 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                1 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                0 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT * , DAY('2014-01-28' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | date | amount | DAY('2014-01-28' - INTERVAL 5 DAY) BETWEEN date - 5 AND date + 5 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |    5 |    200 |                                                                0 |
 |  2 |   15 |    500 |                                                                0 |
 |  3 |   25 |   1000 |                                                                1 |
 +----+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```